# Как изменить .htaccess, что работало ?sort=date ?

Tags: .htaccess

Вот мой файл

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?router=$1 [L]
```

У меня всё работает (т.е. роутеры грузятся правильно). `http://prime/contests/`  - грузит в скрипт переменную `$_GET['router']='contest';` Но если я пишу так  `http://prime/contests/?sort=date`, то переменную sort уже не видит.  Подскажите, как преобразовать .htaccess, чтобы работало `http://prime/contests/?sort=date`.

Поясняю: нужно чтобы `?sort=date` именно прописывалась в url, а не делать так `http://prime/contests/sort/date/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?router=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: @Артур Лоденев если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, нажмите галочку возле правильного ответа. а то я смотрю у вас 88% вопросов висят "без ответа"